# This function in python is printing 'l 2', but returning 0. What am I missing?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, return, return-value

I am calling this function and it is returning 0. But the print gives 2. I am using python2.7. Here's the code:

```
def last_yearcount(d,m,y):
    if d>=13:
        count = 0
        for j in range(1, m+1):
            count = count + int(friday(weekday(13,j,y)) or 0)
        print 'l', count
        return count            
    else:
        last_yearcount(14,m-1,y)
```

Comment: are you sure, the indentation is correct?

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: please add your example too, so we can test the same numbers and try to find your error.

Comment: Did you forget to put `return` in the last line?

Comment: 1. The indentation is correct.

Comment: 2. Thanks. I will remember it next time. The problem was solved by the answer provided

Comment: 4. Not really forget, but I thought that I didn't need to as it was a recursive function and the inside had a return. Was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
return last_yearcount(14,m-1,y)
```

instead:

```
last_yearcount(14,m-1,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive branch of your `if-else` doesn't return any value. Try this:

```
else:
    return last_yearcount(14,m-1,y)
```